# How to Set Text Inside the Responsive Table - Aspect Ratio of Cell and Table Should be 1:1

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-modal

I Designed one Table using Responsive Design. It maintains the width and height as same in all the devices. All Cell should be in same width and height.

```
Cell Height = Responsive Cell Width

+---------+
|   CSS   |
|  Table  |
|   1:1   |
+---------+
```

I want to place the Text within the Cell without collapsing the aspect ratio of the Cell as well as Table and the Text should be formatted.

> Note: Kindly give solution using CSS. Don't use the Javascript or any
>   other raw value feeding. All Cell should be in same width and height.

My HTML Source Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Bootstrap Table</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
td{
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  padding:0 !important;
  
  overflow:auto;
}
td.td-wide{
  height: auto;
}
td div{
  position:absolute;
  width: 25%;
  
}
.placeholder{
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
  <table  class="col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-xs-12"  border="1">
    <tr>
      <td class="col-lg-3">
      <div class='placeholder'>
      
      </div>
      <div>
       as;dfjdj f;s f;sj f;sjdf      
      </div>

      </td>
      <td class="col-lg-3">
        <div>
       as;dfjdj f;s f;sj f;sjdf      
      </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-lg-3"></td>
      <td class="col-lg-3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-lg-3">
      <div class='placeholder'>
      
      </div>
        <div>
      
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="col-lg-6 td-wide">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="col-lg-3"><div>
       as;dfjdj f;s f;sj f;sjdf      
      </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-lg-3">
      <div class='placeholder'>
      
      </div>
        <div>
       as;dfjdj f;s f;sj f;sjdf  k kljsf sdf;ljsd fjsd f;lkjsd f;k jsad;lfkjas d;kk ;fjsadf    
      </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-lg-3">
        <div>
        asdfsadf
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-lg-3">
        <div>
        
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-lg-3">
      <div class='placeholder'>
      
      </div>
      <div>
       as;dfjdj f;s f;sj f;sjdf      
      </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-lg-3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="col-lg-3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D - At the time of Designing the Table, most of us said it is not possible to set the height as same as width. But there is a way to fix it. as like that.

Comment: @Paulie_D give me your kind answer without collapsing the aspect ratio.

Comment: @Paulie_D - give your known answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D - If it is possible with div, give me your answer using div but the design should be same and it should maintain the aspect ratio 1:1

Answer (score 1):

The only method that I am aware of, **using only CSS**, is to abandon tables (which do not react well to positioning) is to use viewport units to create squares.

Note, this limits the size of the 'cells' and the cells will not affect the size of other cells...that requires javascript.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  margin: auto;
}
.child {
  width: 12.5vw;
  height: 12.5vw;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```